# PHP updating field value through AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a table of items, and when the user selects an item i want to set that id to a php variable so when it hits the button "Ok" i associate that item with the user. He can only choose one item at a time. I have tried some php / ajax tutorials and it didn't seem to work.

Here are the codes:

```
<table id="tableItens" style="border:1px solid #000000;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
    <?php foreach($produtoList as $produto) {
        if ($columnCounter == 0) { ?>
            <tr style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
        <?php    
        } 
    ?>              
            <td id="<?php echo $produto['id'] ?>" width=160px; height="110" onclick="<?php echo 'selectRow(' . $produto['id'] . ');' ?>" style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0;"><?php echo'<img align="center" width="150" height="100" src="/resources/images/' . $produto['nome_imagem'] . '"></img>' ?></td>
            <?php $columnCounter++; ?>                  
        <?php if ($columnCounter == 3) { 
            $columnCounter = 0; ?>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>      
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectRow(id) {
  var table = document.getElementById("tableItens");
  document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = 'red';

  $.ajax
  ({
      type: "POST",
      url: "vote.php",
      data: id,
      cache: false,
      success: function(data)
      {

        alert("ok");
      }
 });    
}
</script>
```

Do i have to include a ajax file or something? Maybe a jquery reference?

I'm using a var_dump($_POST) at the beginning of the page and doesn't show anything. I'm sending the value to the same page im in.

Comment: After i changed the data format it worked. But how can i set it to a php variable? Every time user adds a item i want it to show a list of itens added on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set the data of you ajax request correctly.
Refer to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> **data**: Data to be sent to the server...Object must be Key/Value pairs

**NOTE:** it can also be a String, but you have to format it properly

try

```
 data: {uid : id},
```

and of course, you have to include a reference to jQuery, you are using jQuery

To test stuff like this out I suggest using the JS console that usually comes with most modern browsers. You can change POST to GET and see what kind of URLs are generated.

Comment: After i changed the data format it worked. But how can i set it to a php variable? Every time user adds a item i want it to show a list of itens added on the same page.

Answer (score 3):

The answer about the data field being incorrect is right, but something this simple shouldn't be a "POST" it should just be a GET, which doesn't need the 'data' field at all. Just change the URL field to: "vote.php?id=" + id

Like this:

```
$.ajax 
({ 
    type: "GET", 
    url: "vote.php?id=" + id, 
    cache: false, 
    success: function(data) 
    {  
       alert("ok"); 
    } 
});
```